# How to discover what numbers are missing in the resultset?

Tags: java, numbers, logic

I need a help in the logic of this.. i have a resulset,

in this resultset has one column called "Number"

i need to discovery WHAT number is not in it,

example:

```
Number
10
11
12
15
20
21
25
```

i was doing this: taking the actual value as A, doing a `result.next()`, and checking if the actual `value == (A+1)`

ofcourse this dont work, --', since the rows counts = data in the dabatase and not based in the numbers sequence

someone has one tip to make it show the jumped NUMBERS?

```
13
14
16
17
18
19
22
```

.... and go till the last number!!

i throught something like:

```
while(results.next()){
a = previoslyresults("number");

if(actualresult("number") != (a + 1)) {
for(i = 1; i< (actualresults("number") - (a +1));i++) {
 syso("are missing the " (actualresults("number") + i);
}

}
}
```

Comment: There are an infinite number of numbers not in that Result set.

Comment: Loop from the smallest number to the largest number and if your result set does not contain `n`, it means it isn't in the result set.

Comment: generate another set that DOES have all the numbers in it, then diff this complete set against your incomplete set. the result will be the missing numbers.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your problem completely.  Can you show some code to illustrate what you have done?  Or, illustrate a bit better what data you have and what you wish to detect more precisely? thx

Comment: Are the bounds of the set its upper and lower values? If not, how do you figure the bounds?

Comment: @JoshM how do i get the smallest and the largest to make it possible?

Comment: @user2582318 have you tried using `order by number` in your query?

Comment: @Cruncher, yes but what this change?? (of course the order) but it will not return the missing value!! how to take the Last value?

if i have the last, maybe i can check

Comment: @user2582318 : "ofcourse this dont work, --', since the rows counts = data in the dabatase and not based in the numbers sequence" This puts the numbers in sequence, for your original algorithm to work.

Answer (score 0):

you can add all the numbers in an arrayList and  in that checking manually lower and upper bounds and on base of that you can easily get the numbers that are not in the resultset by checking the values by a loop.

Answer (score 0):

This is the sort of solution I would go for, I have included an array version to test it with:

```
class ExpectationChecker
{
    private final boolean[] results;
    private final int min;

    public ExpectationChecker(final int min, final int max)
    {
        this.results = new boolean[max - min + 1];
        this.min = min;
    }

    public Integer[] getMissingNumbers(final ResultSet results) throws SQLException
    {
        while(results.next())
        {
            //Offset by min
            this.results[results.getInt(1) - this.min] = true;
        }
        final List<Integer> missingNums = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < this.results.length; i++)
        {
            if(!this.results[i])
            {
                //Add min in case min isn't 0
                missingNums.add(i + this.min);
            }
        }
        return missingNums.toArray(new Integer[missingNums.size()]);
    }

    public Integer[] getMissingNumbers(final int[] results)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < results.length; i++)
        {
            //Offset by min
            this.results[results[i] - this.min] = true;
        }
        final List<Integer> missingNums = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < this.results.length; i++)
        {
            if(!this.results[i])
            {
                //Add min in case min isn't 0
                missingNums.add(i + this.min);
            }
        }
        return missingNums.toArray(new Integer[missingNums.size()]);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final ExpectationChecker ec = new ExpectationChecker(10, 20);
        final int[] test = {11, 12, 13, 14, 17, 19};
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(ec.getMissingNumbers(test)));
    }
}
```

Which produces the output:

```
[10, 15, 16, 18, 20]
```